# Akka: Adding a delay to a durable mailbox

Tags: scala, queue, message-queue, akka

I am wondering if there is some way to delay an akka message from processing?

**My use case:**  For every request I have, I have a small amount of work that I need to do and then I need to additional work two hours later.

Is there any easy way to delay the processing of a message in AKKA?  I know I can probably setup an external distributed queue such as ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ which probably has this feature but I rather not.

I know I would need to make the mailbox durable so it can survive restarts or crashes.  We already have mongo setup so I probably be using the [MongoBasedMailbox](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/modules/durable-mailbox.html) for durability.

Answer (score 2):

[Temporal Workflow](https://temporal.io/) is capable of supporting your use case with minimal effort. You can think about it as a Durable Actor platform. When actor state including threads and local variables is preserved across process restarts.

Temporal offers a lot of other features for task processing.

- Built it exponential retries with unlimited expiration interval
- Failure handling. For example, it allows executing a task that notifies another service if both updates couldn't succeed during a configured interval.
- Support for long running heartbeating operations
- Ability to implement complex task dependencies. For example to implement chaining of calls or compensation logic in case of unrecoverable failures ([SAGA](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html))
- Gives complete visibility into the current state of the update. For example, when using queues all you know if there are some messages in a queue and you need additional DB to track the overall progress. With Temporal every event is recorded.
- Ability to cancel an update in flight.
- Throttling of requests

See [the presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llmsBGKOuWI) that goes over the Temporal programming model. It talks about Cadence which is the predecessor of Temporal.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but the [Akka Camel Quartz scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/camel.html) would do the trick.  More heavyweight than the built-in ActorSystem scheduler, but know that Quartz has its own issues.

Comment: Can you provide any quote or link on Quartz durability? If there is no such guarantees, why not use [plain scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/scheduler.html)?

Comment: Agreed, if the result from "small amount of work" needs to survive restarts, you just somehow save state during `preRestart`. Durability is for crashes.

Comment: @om-nom-nom - Quartz has a [persistent job feature](http://quartz-scheduler.org/overview/features).

Comment: Camel could work but I am looking for something not so large.

Answer (score 0):

you could still use the normal Akka scheduler, you will just have to keep a state on the actor persistence to avoid loosing the job if the server restarted.

I have recently used PersistentFsmActor - which will keep the state of the actor persisted

I'm not sure in your case you have to use FSM (Finite State Machine) , so you could basically just use a persistentActor to save the time the job was inserted, and start a scheduler to that time. this way - even if you restarted the server, the actor will start and create a new scheduled job use the persistent data to calculate the time left to run it